# Electron Packager - Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir

Tags: node.js, npm, rmdir, electron-packager

I have a script in my package.json (I am on Win10)

```
"build-win32": "electron-packager . --electron-version 1.4.15 --platform win32 --icon ./assets/icon.ico --out ./dist --overwrite"
```

In command prompt I type

```
npm run build-win32
```

I get the error: `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir ...`

So the obvious thing to do (to me ) is close command prompt and restart by right clicking and running as admin. I then type in the admin command prompt

```
npm cache clean
```

I turn off the admin command prompt and restart a normal command prompt. I try running `npm run build-win32` again, but get the same error.

How can I get this working. I have tried `npm cache clean` in a non-admin command prompt as well.

Comment: Check that there is no node process left that could have locked the files. You are not using Atom as IDE ? Sometimes it has exclusive locks.

Comment: I am not sure what this means. I have VS running in the background so I can edit the files.

Comment: Try closing VS and run build again. Also check from task manager that no left over node processes are hanging there.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I have tried everything you have suggested, but sadly they do not work. I shut off VS and the command prompt and then just started the command prompt and tried the build again, but it did not work. I also tried running admin and cleaning, but again it did not work. I have checked the Task Manager and there was nothing showing up there. Thank for the ideas though.